# UIModalTransitionStyle Partial Curl from both corners (or equivalent) possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to create a custom view-controller. In this controller, the main view has to be able to curl up (modaltransitionstylepartialcurl) from both the bottom-right corner and from the bottom-left corner, each triggering a different view. Is this possible to do by somehow reflecting the current partial curl modal transition so it can operate from the other corner as well? Alternately, could this be accomplished by using a UIView animation transition and reflecting that?  Or do I have to build my own animation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do this. You're in for a lot of custom code to pull this off.

Comment: Great - what i suspected. :( Thanks a lot though! Could you point me in the right direction or give me a few pointers or the general layout of how I'd go about accomplishing this? I'm relatively new to Objective-C and this is my first real challenge...

Comment: This is a massive undertaking. Starting with http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/ might work. But as I said, this isn't for the lighthearted. Also that link is a cheap hack, it doesn't do as nice as an effect as Apple's